# how to multiply price with quantity

Tags: javascript, php

I know this question has been asked many times but i could not find the one which fits my contition. So far i have dynamically created a table with checkbox. the rows which are checked are put into an array for futher processing and a table is generated for conformation my only issue here is i am unable to multiply the quantity with price. (Note - all rows have the same id's and names as they are dynamic)
Code -

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
         <thead class="text-danger">
               <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                 <th>Select</th>
            </thead>
<tbody>

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="proname" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; >" />
</td>
<td class="text-warning"><?php echo $row["price"]; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="pri01" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />
</td>
<td>
<div class="numbers-row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qua" id="qua01" value="1" style="cursor:default" disabled />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
      <input id="name" type="checkbox" name="name" value="<?php echo $row["food_id"]; ?>"/>
</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning tble_submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Order</button></center>

 <!-- Here is where the second table is shown which displays only the rows which are checked in the first table -->
 <div id="showData"></div>
```

JS -

```
 $(function() {
$('.tble_submit').click(function(){
    var values = [];
    $("#add input[name=name]:checked").each(function(){

        row = $(this).closest("tr");
        values.push({ 
            Id        : $(this).val(),
            Name      : $(row).find("input[name=proname]").val(),
            Price     : $(row).find("input[name=price]").val(),
            Quantity  : $(row).find("input[name=qua]").val()       
        });
    });

   // console.log(values);
   if(values.length != 0){
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var key in values[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

     var table = document.createElement("table");
     table.setAttribute("class", "table"); 

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = values[i][col[j]];
        }
    }
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);   
} else {
 document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = "XXXX";
}
});

});
```

Comment: well ... multiple elements having the same id will break most javascript concepts relying on ids.

Comment: @Jakumi Thats the actual problem here can you suggest a way arround. Thank you.